bash script conditional not working as expected
I have the following bash script (here's part of it):
  0 #!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                               
  1  
  2 ARGS=2
  3 E_BADARGS=85
  4  
  5 is_number()
  6 {
  7         if [[ "$1" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]];then
  8                 return 0
  9         fi
 10         return 1
 11 }
 12  
 13 [ $# -ne $ARGS ] && {
 14         echo "must have two args!"
 15         exit $E_BADARGS
 16 }
 17  
 18 [ ! is_number "$1" || ! is_number "$2" ] && {
 19         echo "both must be numbers"
 20         exit $E_BADARGS
 21 }

I'm just vomiting code into my editor that I'll cleanup later and so I'm avoiding the use of ifs and thens and just using conditionals.
I'm not sure why:
 13 [ $# -ne $ARGS ] && {
 14         echo "must have two args!"
 15         exit $E_BADARGS
 16 }

works, but:
 18 [ ! is_number "$1" || ! is_number "$2" ] && {
 19         echo "both must be numbers"
 20         exit $E_BADARGS
 21 }

gives me an error, can anyone explain?
The error I get is:
./GCD.sh: line 19: [: missing `]'

but the string: "both must be numbers" is printing...
I ran the script like so:
./GCD.sh 12 s


Don't use braces; if ! is_number "$1" && ! is_number "$2"; then echo both...! ,,, And have a look How do I test if a variable is a number in Bash?

shellcheck says "Expected comparison operator (don't wrap commands in []/[[]])." because you should not put [ .. ] around commands you want to run (/usr/bin/[ is a command in itself, not shell syntax)

The issue is that || will combine commands, so using it ends the previous command. So, the first command, to the left of the ||, is [ ! is_number "$1" and therefore the [ command will rightfully complain about a missing ] in its command line because its invocation syntax is designed to look like a pair of brackets. That's because [ is not shell grammar, it's a command, either in form of a builtin (like echo) or a binary (/bin/[ or /usr/bin/[).

Vomiting code into your editor that you will clean up later is definitely the best way to approach any coding problem. :)
